# Isabelle: Use of the inductive predicate

Tags: transition, state-machine, isabelle

I need to define a predicate word, such that `word u w v` holds iff `w` is a word from `u` to `v`.

I have some defintion

```
type_synonym ('q,'l) lts = "'q ⇒ 'l ⇒ 'q ⇒ bool"

inductive word:: "('q,'l) lts ⇒ 'q ⇒ 'l list ⇒ 'q ⇒ bool" for δ where....
```

and I do not understand it.

Why do you use `type_synomym` and not just

```
inductive word:: " 'q ⇒ 'l list ⇒ 'q ⇒ bool" for δ where....
```

My second question would be on what the δ stands for and how such an inductive can be stated. Is there any tutorial that explains the inductive with maybe more than just one example?

Comment: @rpattiso, Isabelle is a (special-purpose) programming language and there are plenty of questions tagged isabelle here.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Indeed it is, Thanks, retracted.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `lts` stands for labelled transition system. The definition `word` depends on a particular choice of transition system.

The simplified type signature you are proposing is not sufficient: The propositoin `word u w v` makes no sense without specifying which transition system this is a word in.